# How can I solve the same meta title for different subdirectory domain?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, title, subdirectory

I have multiple subdirectory domain (example.com/au, example.com/us,etc) with the same language. I have updated the same title for all of subdirectory domains, but Google just only change 1 of them. Please help me how to solve this problem. Thank you and best regards.

Comment: All the pages have the same title but Google is not displaying it in SERPs? is that right?

Comment: Yes, I have four subdirectory domains, one display the right title from the backend, one change the words order in the title by itself and the last two do not change anything.

Comment: Is it the "site title" that is the problem?   You want a translated site name as part of the titles of the international pages?   For example "Some Page - Site" and (in pig latin): "Omsay Agepay -- IteSay" but it is coming out with the English site name across the board: "Omsay Agepay -- Site"?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you try to find a solution for subdomains, while `example.com/au` and `example.com/us` are subdirectories of `example.com`.

Subdirectories doesn't have different domains but use the same domain, as the main domain is `example.com`.

So you can use any of the subdirectories and respective pages indexing utilities from Google and it should work.